# Sencha Touch Cannot Centre Image and Text

Tags: css, styles, sencha-touch

I've playing around with Sencha Touch for the first time however having difficulties in styling images (i.e. center) and text (i.e. making a certain size/colour).

Could someone please tell me where I add style tags.

Example item below:

```
 // This is the home page, just some simple html
            {
                title: 'Home',
                iconCls: 'home',
                cls: 'home',
                scrollable: true,
                style: 'text-align:centre',
                html: [
                    '<img height=260 src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png"/>',
                    '<h1>Welcome to the Demo HTML5 App</h1>',
                    "<p>Built with Sencha Touch</p>"
                ].join("")
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is not to use STYLE tags... you're assigning a "cls" to the component, which is just a CSS class. Build your styles with CSS:

```
.home img {}
.home h1 {}
.home p {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with arthurkay but if you want to use inline styling you should change ...

```
style: 'text-align:centre'
```

... to ...

```
style: 'text-align:center'
```